# Parameter int in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, variable-assignment

How can I assignment parameter int in Razor view in MVC. Here is my code:

```cs
<div class="pagesize">
@{
   Html.Repeat(new[] { 5, 10, 15 }, ps =>
   {
      if (ps == Model.Search.PageSize)
      {
         @<span>@(ps)</span>; <-- Here I don't know how to assignment or call expression "ps"
      }
      else
      {
         @<a href="@(Url.SetParameters(new {pagesize = ps, page = 1}))">@(ps)</a>;
      }
   }, () => { | });
   <p>Items per page.</p>
}
```

So what code should do ... First the purpose of this line of code is to set how many row in my table I shoudl display. In this case: 5, 10 or 15 rows.

The line of code: @@(ps); shoud return number that user chose. e.g. if user click on 10; in this line @(ps) is 10; second line in else sets rest numbers to ; so if user clicked on 10, @(ps) in this second line is: first is 5, then 15; 10 skips because it is clicked already.

Thanks for help.

Comment: ps is an int variable there, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Maybe you can get some useful info [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/27/templated-razor-delegates.aspx/)

Comment: I am using this documentation: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md Programer in this section use same example, but he used it in aspx, and I am coding it in cshtml. PS is parameter to set how many rows in table I whant to display per page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="pagesize">
@{
   Html.Repeat(new[] { 5, 10, 15 }, ps =>
   {
      if (ps == Model.Search.PageSize)
      {
         ps = 50; <-- Here I don't know how to assignment or call expression "ps"
         var i = ps + 2;
         var s = ps.ToString();
      }
      else
      {
         @<a href="@(Url.SetParameters(new {pagesize = ps, page = 1}))">@(ps)</a>;
      }
   }, () => { | });
   <p>Items per page.</p>
}
```

Comment: So what code should do ... First the purpose of this line of code is to set how many row in my table I shoudl display. In this case: 5, 10 or 15 rows.

The line of code: @@(ps); shoud return number that user chose. e.g. if user click on 10; in this line @(ps) is 10; second line in else sets rest numbers to ; so if user clicked on 10, @(ps) in this second line is: first is 5, then 15; 10 skips because it is clicked already.

Thanks for help.